# How do I make a third party .jar available to my .jsp page?

Tags: java, json, jsp, jar

I'm just starting to learn JSP (and I'm pretty new to Java in general), and I'd like to use [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) with it. I want to make a page something like this:

```
<%@ page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
<%
String json = new JSONObject().put("hello", "world").toString();
out.println(json);
%>
```

I downloaded json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar and put it in the same directory as the .jsp page. But I get this error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. net.sf.json.JSONObject resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /getCard.jsp
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%@ page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject" %>
2: <%
3: String json = new JSONObject().put("hello", "world").toString();
4: out.println(json);
5: %>
6:
```

How do I make the JSONObject class available to my .jsp page?

Comment: Indeed just put it in the classpath. The `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is covered by the classpath. There is however more at matter. You shouldn't be using JSP for this, but a Servlet. JSP may unnecessarily add whitespace to the response and using scriptlets is considered bad practice. As to learning JSP/Servlet the right way, check this site: http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html As to using JSON in JSP/Servlet check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940441#1940441) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589123#2589123) answer.

Comment: @BalusC: Ah, it looks like Servlets are what I want. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to deploy that jar file with your web application. Usually you have to put it in WEB-INF/lib/ folder.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really completely new at this--I don't know what it means to "deploy that jar file with your web application". I found the WEB-INF/lib folder and put the .jar there, but that didn't seem to help anything.

Comment: well .. depending on how your application server is setup up you might need to redeploy the application. But if this seems stange to you (you don't know what this means) you should follow BalusC's link: http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html and start learning from there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem trying to import net.sf.json.JSONArray and got the same error. But when I replaced "JSONArray" with an asterisk, "*", the error went away. Of course, you need to put the JSON-lib.jar file into your {appdir}/WEB-INF/lib directory. [I still have other associated problems with the JSON-lib being used in my JSP, so I'm not sure my answer is all you need.]

Comment: The question is already been answered. Yours concerns a different problem. You need to import `JSONObject` as well. Or just use the wildcard `*` of course. Or better yet, don't write Java code in a JSP file, but in a Java (Servlet) class.