# how to reference external jars inside jsp file

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jdbc, jar

I have  four jsp files. Some of it using JDBC jar file.
And I put all of it in folder webapps/hello like this.

```
index.jsp
login.jsp
userloginmid.jsp
userstatus.jsp

/WEB-INF/
--------/lib/postgres ....jar
```

But it's not work.

I got exception : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

I don't want to use ECLIPSE or something like this.

Just text editor.

Thank.

Comment: Have you added the import at top of JSP files too?

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake, duplicated  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985206/how-do-i-make-a-third-party-jar-available-to-my-jsp-page)